# Im trying to put my discord bot online bit it comes up with an error

Tags: javascript, discord

So here is the error it comes up with when i do node . or node main.js:

```
 throw new DiscordjsRangeError(ErrorCodes.BitFieldInvalid, bit);
    ^

RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: GUILDS.
    at IntentsBitField.resolve (C:\Users\Kaydin Cain\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:168:11)
    at C:\Users\Kaydin Cain\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:163:54
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at IntentsBitField.resolve (C:\Users\Kaydin Cain\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:163:40)
    at new BitField (C:\Users\Kaydin Cain\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:33:38)
    at new IntentsBitField (C:\Users\Kaydin Cain\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\IntentsBitField.js:9:1)
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\Kaydin Cain\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:491:25)
    at new Client (C:\Users\Kaydin Cain\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:78:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Kaydin Cain\Desktop\DiscordBot\main.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14) {
  code: 'BitFieldInvalid'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

Can anyone help?

I tried many things and nothing worked unless there is something wrong with  my code or im doing a command wrong then i have no idea.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.